# Caching DNS using getaddrinfo

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip

I am using system call getaddrinfo() to obtain IP address from DNS.

I will like to know if the cache information is stored on Linux or not?

If the cached information is stored, is it possible to clear the cache information?

I will like to know how to clear the cache information.

Thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, no, the glibc resolver does not cache `getaddrinfo` results.

On systems running [`nscd`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/nscd.8.html), some names may be cached.  (At least, `gethostbyname` may go through cache; I'm not sure about `getaddrinfo`.)  Restart the daemon to clear the cache.

It is usually expected that the upstream (presumably recursive) DNS resolver is performing caching.  In most situations, that is outside of your control.